# Setting file permission for Files and Directories

Tags: linux, file, shell, permissions

I need to apply below permission policies to my files under `www` folder

664 to all files in www recursively, 
755 to all directories under www recursively

I tried

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ; 
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;
```

But always getting error

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Backslash before semi-colon (or quotes around it):

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

The shell sees the semi-colon you typed as the end of the command and does not pass it to `find`, which then complains that it is missing.

Comment: An alternate that I use because I can never remember the -exec syntax is: <code>find . -type f | xargs chmod 0644</code>.

Comment: Me too, Dan.  It also has the potential to execute fewer commands.

Comment: It is important to remember that the 'built-in' notation works correctly for file names with blanks and other odd characters in them.  If you have paths with blanks in them and you are using `xargs`, use the `find` option `-print0` and the `xargs` option `-0`.

Answer (score 2):

Use backslash before ';'

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment: Also you can find file and directoryes at the same time

find . -type f -or -type d

Comment: But since the files need different permissions from the directories, the overall expression has to be rather complex then: `find . \( -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; \) -o \( -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; \)`.  You might be able to avoid the parentheses; they are pretty much guaranteed to work, though.